# Grails 1.4 - What happened to ApplicationHolder, ConfigurationHolder, etc.?

Tags: grails, groovy, app-config

So, all the static holder classes have been deprecated (and are bombing my tests).

What's the new way to get at application metadata, for example? Before, you could use `ApplicationHolder.application.metadata.'blah'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They're been [deprecated in favor of the injection method](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Holders-deprecated-in-1-4-td3549187.html) I believe...

Can you add:

```
def grailsApplication
```

To your classes that require this, then it should be injected at run-time, and you should be able to do:

```
grailsApplication.metadata.'blah'
```

As before?

Configuration is available via:

```
grailsApplication.config
```